# LIME Implementation on LSTM model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, lstm

I am getting an error when I'm trying to use LIME for LSTM model.

Code is below:

```
LIME_exp = LimeTextExplainer.explain_instance(ls_X_test[idx],c.predict_proba,num_features=5)

# print results

print('Document id: %d' % idx)

print('Text: ', ls_X_test[idx])

print('Probability d =', c.predict_proba([ls_X_test[idx]]).round(3)[0,1])

print('True class: %s' % class_names.get(list(y_test)[idx]))
```

Error:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgLAn.png)]

Answer (score 0):

keras does not provide a predict_proba method. Calling predict will give the same results. However, lime does not like the numpy array output of this method. You might have to convert it.